# Cloud Firestore and Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

How can I get the document id of a collection present in the cloud Firestore?

I tried to get it by using the

```
firebase.firestore().collection("collectionName").doc().id
```

but I didn't get the appropriate result.

Comment: What are you trying to execute? get all ids? or get specific id? or get a reference id for future addition of document?

Comment: What is the result that you get? Please reponde with @

Comment: I am trying to get a specific id.

Comment: It returns an ID which is not related to any of the document available in my collection @AlexMamo

Comment: @Saurabhkumar Which looks like?

Comment: It looks like this "aH45ivDiez0ULep04I5q" @AlexMamo

Comment: @Saurabhkumar Please add your database structure.

Comment: Collection : societies, cities                                                                                         societies fields: address, postalCode, societyName, state                                                   cities field: cityName, societyId                                                                                             In the societyId field I want to fetch the document id of the particular societies and for this I write this code firebase.firestore().collection("societies").doc().id and it returns a id which is not equivalent to society documentId @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

> firebase.firestore().collection("societies").doc().id and it returns a id which is not equivalent to society documentId

That's correct because everytime when you are using the above line of code, you are generating a **new** document id which will never be the same with one that already exist in your database.

In order to use a new document id, first you need to generate it (as you already do) and then store it in a variable. Having that varaible which holds that id, you can use it to get that particular document from the database by passing this id as an argument to the `doc(id)` function:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("societies").doc(this.myId)
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?