# Is it possible to get document id of collections available in Firebase Cloud Firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to get the document id of societies collection in cities collection but my code returns a different id in societyId field in the cities collection.

```
myId: string = "";
private docRef: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
this.docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("societies").doc();
this.myId = this.docRef.id;
this.cityList = firebase.firestore().collection("cities").add({
    cityName: this.city,
   societyId: this.myId
}).then((doc) => {
  console.log(doc);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the document id `eh2w ... j041` is different than the societyId property which holds `IEMn ... ngVv`? You need to be the same?

Comment: Yes I need this to be same @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting another `societyId`, which is different than the id that is generated by simply calling `doc()` function because you are adding an object to the database using  CollectionReference's [add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) function:

> Adds a new document to this collection with the specified data, assigning it a document ID automatically.

Instead of using DocumentReference's [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) function:

> Writes to the document referred to by this DocumentReference. If the document does not exist yet, it will be created. If you pass options, the provided data can be merged into the existing document.

According to your comment, if you want to have the same id, please change the following line of code:

```
this.cityList = firebase.firestore().collection("cities").add(/* ... */);
```

to

```
this.cityList = firebase.firestore().collection("cities").doc(this.myId).set(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Please also consider accepting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262704/cloud-firestore-and-ionic) answer. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!